# DaVinci Resolve: hide timeline viewer

Tags: davinci-resolve

I was playing around with Resolve, and managed to show a second window thingy (the black one in the screenshot) via View > Source/Timeline Viewer. Now I can't seem to make it disappear. I have tried Workspace > Layout > Reset UI Layout, but it doesn't remove the second window. How can I remove it?

[image: Resolve]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current way to accomplish this is to either:

1) Toggle the menu [Workspace] > [Single Viewer Mode]

- or -

2) Toggle the [ ] / [][] button (top right of the viewer)

[image]

**NOTE:** Resolve will only enable the options and allow the use of two viewers if it has enough screen space (*screen real estate*) to do so. And that is probably the reason why opening/closing the Inspector affected the dual view.

(Resolve 15)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon one way of doing this, and that is to click "Inspector" at the top right of the UI:

[image: Resolve screenshot - Inspector]

Comment: actually, as soon as you play something in the source viewer, the inspector window closes and the timeline viewer closes, so this doesn't help.

Comment: I can't remember my workflow, but it certainly worked for me.